# java compile command line

Tags: java, command-line, intellij-idea

I wrote a program in the Intellij IDEA. It runs fine in the IDE but I am having problems with it from the command line (I so very rarely run my own from the command line I think I am just missing a step.) So here is the problem.
If I navigate to where my file is:

```
cd averageAmpCov/src/
```

and then run my program it works fine:

```
java averageAmpCov

Error: Parameter 'out' is required.
Error: Parameter 'in' is required.
Usage: java averageAmpCov
       (-o|--outputlocation) <out> (-i|--inputlocation) <in>

  (-o|--outputlocation) <out>
        Where is the input file to be put? Full path and desired file name

  (-i|--inputlocation) <in>
```

But when I try to run from outside the folder like this:

```
java averageAmpCov/src/averageAmpCov
```

I get a sad error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: averageAmpCov/src/averageAmpCov (wrong name: averageAmpCov)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Some other posts say that it might be a class path problem, but I am not really understanding what to do. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: java -cp averageAmpCov/src/ averageAmpCov

Comment: You need to include the classpath using the -cp parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to run your program outside the class folder, set the classpath to the directory in which your .class file is located:

```
java -cp averageAmpCov/src averageAmpCov
```

Now you won't get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.  The classpath is where Java looks to find .class files to load and run.  The class name argument must be the actual class name, no directories involved.

Comment: If the OP does this, he/she would get the first error (parameters 'in' and 'out' required).

Comment: @EtienneMiret True, but that's not the problem the OP is asking about; it's the `NoClassDefFoundError` that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @EtienneMiret I know what the error means, I set my program to tell me that so that I put in the right args. If that shows up, it means that my program was found and is running correctly

Comment: @rgettman I tried as you suggested but this is what I got java -cp averageAmpCov/src/ averageAmpCov
Error: Could not find or load main class averageAmpCov  Do I need to javac in a special way?

Comment: @user2076476 Given the directory structure in your question, this solution should have worked.

Comment: @user2076476 Does your class have a package name?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad If the OP is in the proper directory and `java averageAmpCov` works, then there is no package on the class.

Comment: @rgettman Sorry. I am crazy. I navigated away from where I was supposed to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use `java` correctly, you should ensure that:

1. You use the fully-qualified class name of the main class.
2. The main class should be in the classpath.

The classpath can be set in 3 ways:

1. It can be set within the environment variable `CLASSPATH`.
2. With the option `-cp` which would overwrite `CLASSPATH`.
3. If you don't use neither, then the current directory is the classpath.

Note that if the structure of the files as follows:

```
bin -
     |
     com -
         |
         mypackage -
                   |
                   Hello.class
```

and `Hello`'s package name is `com.mypackage`, then the following command should work:

```
java -cp C:\projects\myprojct\bin com.mypackage.Hello
```

Alternatively, you can `cd` to `C:\projects\myprojct\bin` and just use:

```
java com.mypackage.Hello
```

Answer (score -2):

Running this is fine

java averageAmpCov/src/averageAmpCov

BUT i guess u forgot to set ur classpath set class path first

Comment: No, it is not. java does not take directory name, but class name.

Comment: Please check your spelling.